# How to chain Result Monads using Monadex?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, monads

### Background

In my quest to learn more about [Monadex](https://github.com/rob-brown/MonadEx) I am trying to chain a Result Monad several times in a function.
I understand this is achieved via the [fmap](https://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html), a function which takes a function and a Monad and returns a Monad.

```
defmodule TestMonadex do
  use Monad.Operators

  import Monad.Result

  # This wont work
  def p2(x) do
    x
    |> success()
    <|> (&plus_1/1)
    <|> (&plus_1/1) 
  end

  defp plus_1(n), do: n + 1
end
```

### Problem

The problem here is that according to the documentation, Result Monad does not implement the `fmap`:

https://hexdocs.pm/monadex/Monad.Result.html#content

### Question

- Why can't my example work?
- How can I chain the Result Monad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a brief dive into the source, the `<|>` operator in monadex seems to have its arguments reversed compared to `Functor.fmap`. So this works:

```elixir
(&plus_1/1) <|> (&plus_1/1) <|> success(x)
```

This also works:

```elixir
success(x) |> Functor.fmap(&plus_1/1) |> Functor.fmap(&plus_1/1)
```

Not sure if it's by design or a bug - the documentation is quite sparse. Perhaps the idea is that you first build a computation with `<|>` and finally apply it to a value, maybe even in another part of the code?